# MS Power Query: Create date from month, day, year

Tags: date, powerquery

How do I create in Power BI Desktop the date from separate columns with data for month, day and year.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example:

```
Table.AddColumn(<NameOfPreviousQueryStep),"Date", each #date([year],[month],[day]))
```